# Quick game with player criteria - realtime multiplayer android google play services

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

i am currently developing a realtime multiplayer game for android and i got the example ButtonClicker working. I think the "quick game"(or maybe it´s called automatch) option is just what i need. But i need something like this: I would like to make the player play a match with a random player from his level. You see, on my game, every player will have a level and these levels and associated players will maybe be stored on a database. I want the player to have a quick game with only the players from his level. Is it possible to inform that criteria on quick game? What must i do?

I also want him to be able to choose his friends(the invite option) but only friends that are on his level.

Answer (score 2):

In order to restrict automatching between players, you can use the variant option when building a room configuration, ie [RoomConfig.Builder#setVariant(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.Builder.html#setVariant%28int%29).

In order to restrict invitations, I think you will have to create your own "invite player" activity, which I am less familiar with. You will presumably have to query for the player's friends, and then cross-correlate this list with each of their "levels" and filter it down to those of the same level before showing it in the activity. It looks like The [Players](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.html) API has some methods that you will be able to interact with, and hopefully would contain an Id that you use in your level-based DB.

Rob

Comment: thanks for asking. I knew about the method above, but i still don´t know what kind of ints i can pass to it. And i think the method create(GoogleApiClient, RoomConfig) which uses the variant of setVariant it´s not a method i can declare and modify. It looks like a method that i can only call. Can you tell me how could i use setVariant so i can achieve what i want?

Comment: i think the only automatch criteria i can create with google api is the max and min number of players. Is there a way to create a new criteria?

Comment: The setVariant(int) can be used to limit who automatches.

Comment: Only two players requesting an automatch with the same int value variant will be paired together. Thus, I assume that the "level" of your players is a perfect fit for the variant.
When you are building the Room config, call this setVariant method passing in the current player's "level". This will limit the automatic matching of any players that are attempting an automatch at that time.


   `RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(strategy);
   rtmConfigBuilder.setVariant(variant);
   ....
   Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(apiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());`

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! i will try it. Thanks a lot, i had no idea that i could do that. It really helped ^^

Answer (score 0):

When you create your RoomConfig for match making you can provide AutoMatchCriteria. The API just uses a bitmask, so it is up to you what data you put in that bit mask:

[createAutoMatchCriteria](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig.html#createAutoMatchCriteria(int,%20int,%20long))

> **exclusiveBitMask**: Exclusive bitmasks for the automatching request. The
>   logical AND of each pairing of automatching requests must equal zero
>   for auto-match. If there are no exclusivity requirements for the game,
>   this value should just be set to 0.

In your case this could contain a level range to match up with.

You can see it being used in the sample code here: [Developing Real-Time Multiplayer Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#invite_players_option).